# JTextField couldn't hold enter chars

Tags: java, swing

I am copying a JTextArea's content to a `JTextField` and then getting the same text from `JTextField` and setting to `JTextArea`. But at last case; all text is coming in same line. Enters are missing. How can I protect the content?

Comment: `JTextField` is inherently a one line control, so it won't store new line characters - if you want it to, then you need another `JTextArea` instead.

Answer (score 1):

yourJTextArea.setLineWrap(true) I think it's what you are looking for if I understood your question correctly.